# How does `*(*(p+1)+1)[7]` equal `p[1][8][0]`?

Tags: c, pointers

`char *p[2][3];`

How does `*(*(p+1)+1)[7]` equal `p[1][8][0]`?

I thought `*(*(p+1)+1)[7]` would be the same as `*(*(*(p+1)+1)+7)` and that is equal to `p[1][1][7]`, where am I wrong?

E: I don't understand why this is being downvoted...

Comment: How do you define p?

Comment: Postfix `[]` has higher precedence than unary `*`.

Comment: Forgot to add that, @Elipzer. It's a `char *p[2][3]`. Thanks.

Comment: @EOF So `*(*(p+1)+1)[7]` should be `*(*(p+1)+1+7)`?

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD: Well, now you're missing a `*`. It's `**(*(p+1)+1+7)`.

Comment: Ohh, I see, it's like the argument 'gets inside' the parenthesis, and then you add the `*`? (Sorry, I'm trying to get a general rule to understand these declarations).

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD: I'd recommend learning about context-free grammars, and then reading the C-standard, it contains the exact rules.

Comment: TBH, I would not want either in my code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Basic facts:

1. `[]` [associates](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) left to right
2. `[]` has higher [precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) than the dereference operator `*`
3. `a[i]` is `*(a+i)`

So

```
  *(*(p+1)+1)[7] 
= *((*(p+1)+1)[7])   // rule 2
= *(*(*(p+1)+1+7))   // rule 3
= *(*(*(p+1)+8))    
= *(*(*(p+1)+8)+0)  
= p[1][8][0]         // rules 1 and 3
```

Answer (score 2):

This depends on the relative precedence of `[]` vs unary `*` (the former is higher), and the essential identity that if `p` is (or evaluates to) a pointer and `n` is of integer type then `p[n]` means the same thing as `*(p + n)`.  You can therefore transform your starting expression according to the following steps, making repeated use, in both directions, of that identity:

1. `*(*(p+1)+1)[7]`
2. == `*((*(p+1)+1)[7])`  (The added parentheses express the operator precedence explicitly.)
3. == `*((p[1]+1)[7])`
4. == `*(*((p[1]+1)+7))`
5. == `*(*(p[1]+1+7))`
6. == `*(*(p[1]+8))`
7. == `*(p[1][8])`
8. == `*(p[1][8] + 0)`
9. == `p[1][8][0]`

Answer (score 1):

```
  *(*(p+1)+1)[7]
= *(p[1] + 1)[7]
```

Due to operator precedence ( `[]` is higher than `*`), that expression

```
= *((p[1] + 1)[7])
= *(*((p[1] + 1 + 7))
= *(*(p[1] + 8 ))
= *(p[1][8])
=  p[1][8][0]
```